# Is there such a thing as a continuous metric space?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

If one looks at the set of real numbers equipped with absolute value metric, then we notice that any open interval of any size is non empty. I was wondering if continuity of any metric space could be defined this way. Intuitively it seems to me like if open balls of all radii (no matter how small) around all elements of a metric space are non empty then the metric space is "continuous" in some vague way. Is there more to this? Essentially what I'm saying is that $(X,d)$ is a "continuous" metric space if and only if  $\forall x \in X$ and $\forall \epsilon > 0$ the open ball without the centre,

$$B_\epsilon(x) = \{y\in X: d(x,y) < \epsilon, y \neq x\}$$

is non empty.

Comment: That set is always non empty, since $x$ belongs to it.

Comment: Oh right, I meant  the open ball with the Centre removed. I'll edit it

Comment: There is also the concept of a complete metric space, which together with perfectness gives an even more intuitive feeling of "continuous"

Answer (score 2):

Welcome, Pranav!  The term for this is **dense-in-itself**, which I must admit is quite a bit less pleasant-sounding than your term ‘continuous’.  (But ‘continuous’ is already used for functions, so I can see why people wouldn't use it here.)

In general, a point $ x $ of a metric space is called **isolated** if, for some sufficiently small positive number $ \epsilon $, the open ball $ B _ \epsilon ( x ) $ is equal to just $ \{ x \} $ (so as empty as it could be).  So you're looking for a space with no isolated points, which (as I mentioned) is called ‘dense-in-itself’ for some reason.

[Wikipedia tells me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense-in-itself) that such a space can also be called **crowded**, although I haven't heard that term myself.  As @MoisheKohan pointed out in a comment, you can also call it a [**perfect** space](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/perfect+space).  But [Wikipedia also says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_set#:%7E:text=perfect%20space) that ‘perfect space’ sometimes has other meanings.

(When considered as *subsets* of another space, there's a difference between dense-in-itself/crowded and perfect, since a perfect subset is also required to be closed.  But when considered as a space in its own right, anything is closed, so the two concepts become the same thing.  I've heard of a dense-in-itself space, and thanks to Moishe's comment, I've heard of a perfect space; but it may be that ‘crowded’ is only used when considering a subset of some ambient space, which is the context of the Wikipedia article.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Toby! that makes a lot of sense, and I'll look further into it. Regards.

Comment: A bit better (AFIAC) name is [perfect](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/perfect+space).

Comment: @MoisheKohan :  Good point!  I've added a bit more about how the terms are used for a subset of an ambient space, as opposed to a space by itself.